# Problems with Laravel Forge deploy and Git

Tags: php, git, laravel

Recently I set up Laravel Forge, but I keep having issues with deployment. It always throws errors during deployment - I've pasted them below.

How can I solve this?

```
U   app/storage/logs/laravel.log
U   vendor/autoload.php
U   vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
U   vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

Answer (score 0):

"Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files."

- Option 1 - You are probably manually changing the files on the server, which you shouldn't.
- Option 2 - You are storing the vendor file on git, which you shouldn't, and is having conflicts (you shouldn't save the vendor folder on git)

Answer (score 0):

Just execute `git stash` on the server in the directory of the project, and all be good to deploy